# How to load column dynamically in Excel given the row

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have an Excel sheet with a cell E11 for example with value 8.

And I would like load the value dynamically via formula in B row, something like:

```
=$B8
```

But with loaded with E11 cell:

```
=$B$(E11)
```

But this doesn't work. I don't know if I need use a function for this or how I call load this exactly

Comment: Fuzzy question. Maybe you meant `=INDEX(B:B,E11)`?

Comment: To write "B8" You should use `="B"&E11`. To obtain the value from "B8" you should use `=INDIRECT("B"&E11)`. It would be good to explain what you are trying to accomplish. Now, we are trying to guess...

Comment: i think shakaran mean the `indirect()` solution .. right @shakaran ?

Comment: Thanks, the right question was =INDIRECT("B"&E11). This is useful for me since I do later fetching via ROW. if @FaneDuru put as answer I will mark as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the value from "B8", try using  `=INDIRECT("B"&E11)`, please.